# Как сделать ленивую загрузку текстур?

Tags: android

Как можно реализовать `ленивую` загрузку контента в приложение?

В некоторых играх дополнительный контент подгружается по согласию пользователя, уже после запуска приложения. Как реализовать подобный механизм?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Видимо вам необходимо загрузить с сервера файлы изображений, а потом загрузить их в текстуры.

Comment: @Unick, меня интересует сам принцип, под конкретный движок уже найду реализацию. Пока все, что я видел это загрузка локальных текстур.

Comment: Т.е. ваш вопрос можно свести к тому, как после запуска приложения подгружать файлы с сервера? В вашей ситуации изображения.

Comment: @Unick, хотелось подгружать  изображение (по требованию)  на устройство и в дальнейшем пользоваться им как локальным ресурсом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается это примерно так.

Допустим имеется `ImageView`, в который надо загрузить большой файл из внешнего источника. Принципиально загрузка текстуры мало чем отличается от загрузки картинки, поэтому это можно опустить.

1) Надо озаботиться заглушкой/stub'ом картинки. Ее можно или заранее сгенерировать и положить в ресурсы или можно сгенерировать программно в виде Thumbnail, например так:

```
 Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
          BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

2) В момент развертки лейаута, грузим вместо нашего `ImageView` заглушку/thumbnail

3) Далее запускаем `AsyncTask` в котором грузим изображение с внешнего источника в методе `doInBackground()`. При завершении `AsyncTask` в методе `onPostExecute()` - уже заменяем заглушку скачанной картинкой.

Либ делающих такой джоб много, например [universalImageloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) или новомодная [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)